# jQuery AJAX call getting HTML response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an AJAX call in a `.aspx` file:

```
var data = { "schoolID": id };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: "schools.aspx/DeleteSchool"
    , data: JSON.stringify(data)
    , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    , dataType: "json"
    , error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.alert({
            title: "Error deleting school"
            , type: "red"
            , content: XMLHttpRequest + "||\n" + textStatus + "||\n" + errorThrown
        });
});
```

It's called when a button is clicked. It's supposed to pass an id to this C# function:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteSchool(int schoolID)
{
    string query = @"
        DELETE
        FROM tableName
        WHERE id = @schoolID
    ";

    List<SQLParameter> parameters = new List<SQLParameter> {
        new SQLParameter("@schoolID", schoolID)
    };

    SqlConn.doQuery(query, parameters);
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint in the C# function, it never breaks and the error function in the AJAX object always runs. The error looks like this:

[image: image of error in Firefox Developer Edition]

In Chrome, it looks like this:

[image: image of error in Chrome]

The response come back as HTML:

[image: image of response]

[image: image of response]

When I check the parameters of the request, it seems the JSON object that I pass is formatting correctly, so I'm not exactly sure what's wrong here, or why the `WebMethod` is never hit. I checked the [MDN documentation for the 302 code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=devtools-netmonitor&utm_campaign=default), but I'm not sure if that's related to my problem at all. Based on my research, it appears that AJAX is expecting JSON instead of HTML and can't parse the response, but I'm confused as to why, since the return of the `WebMethod` is void and it isn't being hit anyway. Why am I getting an HTML response and why isn't my `WebMethod` being called?

Comment: Check what the actual HTML is. Given you're running ASP.Net, it's probably a YSOD which will give you some information about the problem. Better still, set a breakpoint and step through the code.

Comment: The HTML is the landing page of the site. I've stepped through the code in the Firefox debugger several times and I can't see what's wrong. It just goes straight to the error function.

Comment: Based on that error, maybe this will help: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data))`.

Comment: @I.R.R. I tried that and it threw an exception: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue comes from the way my organization handles requests.

Answer (score 0):

your url in the ajax call need to  be

url: "http://localhost:56302/context/Math/schools.aspx/DeleteSchool"

Comment: I tried that and got the exact same thing. We don't use the full URL in any of the AJAX calls on our other pages.

Comment: are you using Areas in your app?

Comment: No, I am not using areas.